Checking if a coin flipping game had a winner

Suppose there is a game where 1000 people flip a fair coin.
In round 1, everyone who had tails is eliminated.
In round 2, the remaining people flip coins again, of the remaining people, everyone who had tails is out.
This keeps going until everyone is out.

Here is my R simulation to represent this:
# pre game set up

num_players <- 1000
results <- data.frame(player = paste0("player", 1:num_players))
status <- rep("playing", num_players)
round <- 1

# simulation
while (any(status == "playing")) {
    
    coin_flips <- ifelse(runif(num_players) > 0.5, "heads", "tails")
   
    current_round <- ifelse(status == "playing", coin_flips, "eliminated")
    
 
    status <- ifelse(status == "playing" & coin_flips == "tails", "eliminated", status)
    
   
    results <- cbind(results, current_round)
    
    colnames(results)[ncol(results)] <- paste0("round_", round)
    
    round <- round + 1
}

The results look like this:
 > head(results)
   player round_1    round_2    round_3    round_4    round_5    round_6    round_7    round_8    round_9   round_10
1 player1   heads      heads      heads      heads      heads      heads      tails eliminated eliminated eliminated
2 player2   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated
3 player3   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated
4 player4   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated
5 player5   tails eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated
6 player6   heads      tails eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated eliminated


I am trying to answer the following question: After the result of the simulation, can we see if this game had a unique winner? That is, was there a moment in which all other 999 players were eliminated but one player had still not been eliminated? (i.e. no ties)

Suppose we repeat this simulation 1000 times. Can we plot the result of each simulation and see how many winners each simulation had? (e.g. game 1 had 3 winners, game 2 had 1 winner, game 3 had 4 winners, etc)



thank you ... can you please show me how to do this? I will try in the meantime ...

You can try the following code. I've highlighted the lines that I have added to your code and removed unnecessary code (eg. rounds).
set.seed(123) # for reproducibiltiy

nsims <- 1000
SIMS <- vector("list", length=nsims)  # initialize the results
for(i in 1:nsims) {  # iterate over all simulations 
  results <- data.frame(player = paste0("player", 1:num_players))
  status <- rep("playing", num_players)
  while (any(status == "playing")) {
    coin_flips <- ifelse(runif(num_players) > 0.5, "heads", "tails")
    current_round <- ifelse(status == "playing", coin_flips, "eliminated")
    status <- ifelse(status == "playing" & coin_flips == "tails", "eliminated", status)
    results <- cbind(results, current_round)
  }
  SIMS[[i]] <- results  # store the results of this simulation
}

Sims contains the results in a list, which you can access. The number of rows of each element in the list that matches your criteria (not eliminated) tells you how many winners there were for each simulation.
winners <- sapply(SIMS, function(x) nrow(x[x[, ncol(x)] !="eliminated",]))
plot(winners, type="h", xlab="Round")


table(winners)
winners
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
724 172  64  23   8   3   3   3

